# what this warning means?

Tags: sql, sql-server

A column insert or update conflicts with a rule imposed by a previous CREATE RULE statement. The statement was terminated. The conflict occurred in database 'Personneli', table 'dbo.tblPersonnelFighter', column 'StartValidDate'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Is it related to c# or sql ? What is the situation of this error? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

It means there's a constraint on the column `StartValidDate` in the table `tblPersonellFighter` of the `Personeli` database. Your SQL does not comply to the rules of this constraint, hence the failure.